# Is there a way to decrease the auto-hide delay for dockable windows in ArcMap 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, ux

I'd like for my dockable windows to hide a little faster than they do now.  Is this a user or application setting within ArcMap or ArcGIS?

More details: I'm specifically interested in ArcMap, but if it's one setting for the entire ArcGIS desktop--I'll take it.

Comment: You _might_ be able to turn off docking shadows completely if I read [this](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38474) correctly. That might increase the close speed a little.

Comment: Good suggestion, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: I just figured out that hitting the escape key will immediately hide the window--good enough workaround for me.

Comment: @JayCummins, I'd post and accept that as the answer. True it doesn't address the Q as asked, but sometimes the best answer is one the comes from outside the initially conceived scope. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hitting the escape key will immediately hide the window.

Answer (score 0):

If there was it would probably be in the [Advanced ArcMap Settings](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000300000018000000.htm) utility. As it's not, I don't think this is possible -- unless there is a .NET-wide registry setting somewhere that the ArcGIS applications also use.

Comment: What does this have to do with .NET?

Comment: I thought the ArcGIS 10 applications were in .NET now.